# Java: Is It Better Practice to Return an ArrayList or to Update Directly in Method

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, composition

Say, for example, I have an `array` of `Object` that I will be iterating through in a helper method; in the helper function, I will be extracting and processing the relevant/important information and adding it to an `ArrayList`.

**My questions are as follow:**

***QUESTION ONE***

Is it better to pass in a newly created `ArrayList` as a parameter/argument and update directly in the helper function **OR** is it better to create an `ArrayList` in the helper function and subsequently return it to my main function for assignment? Either way, it works in that my `ArrayList` is updated, but which is the better practice, and why? What are some potential drawbacks?

**Option 1**

```
ArrayList<SomeType> newArrayList = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
Array myArray = something.getSomeArray();
saveArrayToArrayList(myArray, newArrayList);

private static void saveArrayToArrayList(Array myArray, ArrayList<SomeType> newArrayList) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.size(); j++) {
        /* processing myArray[j] to get "SomeType newItem" */
        newArrayList.add(newItem);
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
Array myArray = something.getSomeArray();
ArrayList<SomeType> newArrayList = saveArrayToArrayList(myArray);

private static ArrayList<SomeType> saveArrayToArrayList(Array myArray) {
    ArrayList<SomeType> newArrayList = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.size(); j++) {
        /* processing myArray[j] to get "SomeType newItem" */
        newArrayList.add(newItem);
    }
    return newArrayList;
}
```

I had been thinking about this for a while while Googling around. For me, the second option seems more obvious (perhaps due to my background) but I think efficient Java users will argue that you are not a *true* Java user if it isn't obvious to you that the `ArrayList` gets updated either way anyway. So, which is better? :S Or, is this a stupid question? :S

***QUESTION TWO***

Secondly, for each option, how should the helper method be named to make what is going on really clear and obvious to everyone who reads my code? `saveArrayToArrayList` sounds pretty bad to me, hah!

Comment: Option 2 is recommend way.  Assume a scenario where you are passing an argument to two method for example. List a = new List(); fun1(a); fun2(a);   . In this particular scenario fun2 may behave unexpectedly if fun1 has modified the list a.

Comment: @Hemant That is definitely a consideration, especially as the project gets bigger.

Comment: Option 1 can save multiple Arrays to single ArrayList.  It is the difference.

Comment: I would appreciate it if the downvoter could explain why he/she downvoted this question. It is rather passive-aggressive and useless, if I may say so, to downvote without leaving an explanation/elaboration on why this question is a bad one.

Comment: Java SE uses option 1 for a method almost identical to your example. [`Collections.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-)

Comment: @Radiodef Constructor `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> e)` is option 2.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for the link. `Collections.addAll` has been suggested as an answer below. Would appreciate it if you could read the comments, :)

Comment: `Collections.addAll` is actually different from what is suggested in that answer. ; ) And I did read the comments.

Comment: @Radiodef How is it different?

Comment: [`Collections.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-)/[`Collection.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) One is a static method which takes an array, the other is an instance method which takes another collection. *(Edit: but this is totally beside the point. My point was that SE uses option 1.)*

Answer (score 1):

None of the above methods are recommended on ArrayLists.

You should use `addAll()`.

Something like this :

```
originalArrayList.addAll(newArrayList);
```

Comment: Uh, I am a bit confused by what you are suggesting. I start off with an `Array` of `Object`, not an `ArrayList`? Or do you mean to say that option 2, which returns an `ArrayList` rather than updates it directly should be modified in how the returned `ArrayList` is assigned?

Comment: The use new `Array.asList` and convert it to an ArrayList.

Comment: That is actually not an option in this case, I believe. The `Objects` contain a lot of information, some of which I do not wish to keep, some of which needs to be further processed. At the end of the day, what I am looking to do is this: I am iterating through the `Array` of `Objects`, creating new `Objects` that are succinct and sufficient for my purpose, and adding them to an `ArrayList`, as I have explained at the very top of my question.

Comment: In either case , you are looping through the array while you are adding it to the arraylist, while there is already a function in Arraylist which does it for you. Performance wise it is always better to use the methods that come with the package. I am talking about the part of your method where you are adding the arraylists to another. That is not required.

Comment: So, you are suggesting that I just use `newArrayList.addAll(myArray.asList())` and then proceed to iterate through my newArrayList to do the abovementioned processing that I require? I find that tedious because then I will have to remove the fields that I don't want, etc.

Comment: I am suggesting when you add the it to the array, use the above process. If you know which objects you need to modify, then first modify those and then appending it to the existing arraylist the way I suggested.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that `toList`, followed by iteration through the new `ArrayList` to do the necessary modifications, followed by `addAll` will be more efficient?

Comment: Yes. That to me looks the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are acceptable, based on your situation (i.e. passing in an object to modify vs. returning one). If your method gets or creates something, you can return it. If you want to modify the internals of something, pass it into the method as a param. Note you can only return one object, so passing in an object to be modified with 2 or more return values may necessitate the need for the first method.

For naming, if you return something from a member variable, it is a getter, so a suggestion would be to prefix the method with "get" e.g. getArrayList(). For java, "get" identifies the method **may be** a property accessor as a part of POJO, so you set yourself for success by getting into the habit, as a java programmer, of using **get**Whatever() a lot in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @MuffinMan